# Angular - dynamic form template and controls derived from a class

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an app which includes a form (reactive) with a set of predefined fixed controls.
This form has an input binding of a generic class in which the **type** implements an interface, as following:

```
export interface Interactive {
  getId(): string | number;
  getName(): string;
  getCode(): string;
  getAdditionalProps(): any;
  getDefaultOutputType(): PdfOutputType;
  getOutputTypes(): PdfOutputType[];
  getForm(): any; // <---- NEED to implement this
}

export class InteractiveField<T extends Interactive = InteractiveFieldType> {
  id: number;
  type: T;
  isSelected = false;
  settings: FieldSettings;

  constructor(field: Partial<InteractiveField<T>>, type: T){ ...  }

}

export class SomeField implements Interactive {
  // implementations for interface methods
}

// FORM COMPONENT
export class FieldFormComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() field: InteractiveField;
  fieldForm: FormGroup;
  ...
}
```

What I need is to be able to add a method which will return an additional set of controls to be added to the predefined form as well as the template.

I thought of getting the root Injector (using a function which will set it on bootstrap of `AppModule`) -> then getting a service which will create the "additional" form component dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver` ->  add it to view container (`ViewContainerRef`).
In this case however I'm not sure on how to define the dynamic component's `FormGroup` and expose its controls to the "initial" (predefined) form.

How would you suggest to implement it?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-form) - as you will see, there are:

1. `InteractiveField` (class) which is the base class used - it has common properties such as size and position and also a `Type` - which implements the `Interactive` interface from the example
2. `InteractiveFieldSub` and `OtherInteractiveFieldType` which are types implementing `Interactive` interface. Each has its own props - but they are used "inder" `InteractiveField`

The form should be editing both `InteractiveField` settings (size, position and others) and also some properties of it's `type` - in which each type should provide its own controls and form to be added to the 'main' form.

Comment: please paste your HTML code and what about your control validations? is those are also dynamic?

Comment: Well, its a standard form used in a ```formGroup``` property in the component with ```formControlNames``` (will post it later) - validators will be standard ones (required)

Comment: That I know, but it's not clear what you need?

Comment: get a form template and controls from a class and add them to the "main" form as I mentioned in my OP.

Comment: that's very easy to bind a new template with control. I believe that you can do easily,It will be good if you provide the stackblitz example with problem staement, if still you are looking for a good solution.

Comment: yeah, we need a stackblitz, it's not clear what your problem is

Comment: Added stackblitz in OP